# how adjust double value to approximate value after 

Tags: android

i am getting double values,i need to reduce to approximative value after . for example

i have 123.678,i need to format this as 124.

if  i have 123.212 i need to format this as 123

how can i done this,can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Math.round()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29) for floats or [Math.round()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) for doubles

> **public static int round(float a)**
>
> **public static long round(double a)**
>
> Returns the closest int/long to the
> argument.
>
> The result is rounded to an
> integer by adding 1/2, taking the
> floor of the result, and casting the
> result to type int/long.
>
> In other words,
> the result is equal to the value of
> the expression: (int)Math.floor(a + 0.5f) or (long)Math.floor(a + 0.5d)

Comment: Seriously? `double d = 123.678d; long n = Math.round(d);`

Comment: when i click on calculate button it displays result when it's position is portrait if i change the orientation then it will disappear it's value how i will handle to ovecome this problem. t mean the value should be appear when orientation changes also kindly help me anyone to quesions  in android

Comment: this is not related u can follow separate question tag

Comment: hi all how android code for write asynchronous class to display elements one by one  help me anyone