# unable to get the 2 values after decimals but getting zero

Tags: android, double, decimalformat

Hi friends I want to get two values after decimal,but in my I am getting 0 after the decimal. this is my code below.

```
  if (!ed.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                            int input = Integer.valueOf(ed.getText().toString());
                            double out = input / 24;
                            out = (double)Math.round(out * 100)/100;
                            Intent m = new Intent(Page.this,MActivity.class);
                            m.putDoubleExtra("res", out);
                            startActivity(m);
```

I referred these sites also: [Android : How to get just two digit after the point in decimal value ? dont want to trunc the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643995/android-how-to-get-just-two-digit-after-the-point-in-decimal-value-dont-want)

[Java : how do I get the part after the decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890472/java-how-do-i-get-the-part-after-the-decimal-point)

and I tried the code below also but it getting 0 after decimal.

```
DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double twoDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(d))
```

Please help me new to coding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double twoDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(d))

In your code i found is

out = (double)Math.round(out * 100.0)/100.0;

Comment: I getting the result 0 only

Answer (score 1):

Since `input` and `24` are integers, when you divide it, it still produces `int`. Only then it is converted to double.

One way to solve this: `double out = input / 24.0;`